# Cannot email multiple users in SharePoint Group

Tags: wss-3.0

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and when I select all users in a group(i.e 20 users), the email function just hangs.  However, if I select 2 users in the same group, the email function works. This is what I do, go into Site Settings/People and Groups>select the appropriate group>select all>click Actions tab>Email Users.  Are there limitations to how many users can go through an email?